# How to fix import/no-named-as-default ESlint rule when you want to change the name of a default import?

Tags: reactjs, import, eslint, es6-modules

I have the following warning from ESlint import plugin:

> eslint - import/no-named-as-default: use default import syntax to import clearRegister.

```
import { default as clearRegister } from "./utils/form/clearForm";
```

Here I am using `default as` to rename my default imported function to clearRegister. This renaming works as a charm.

```
//clearForm.js
export default function clearForm() {
 ...
}
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Invalid
import { default as clearRegister } from "./utils/form/clearForm";

// Valid
import clearForm from "./utils/form/clearForm";
```

Check here: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-named-as-default.md